# Cannot execute crontab command from a php script...from shared host

Tags: php, cron

I'm running an application where I need to execute the cron job, once a form is submitted,contains more than 1 lac records in a loop(its on-demand execution of cron job and deletes the job once finished).

I'm using php, I tried to configure the job through cpanel as a test and it works...the command was.."/ramdisk/bin/php5 -f /home/user/public_html/domain/cron.php -q", it worked fine.

But when I tried to run the same job with the exec() of php, like I wrote this whole command to a file (I do not know where the original crontab file is located otherwise could have written to it, please suggest a way to find its location) and ran that file like "exec("crontab /home/user/cron/Feed_cron"); ", in this cron is not working...

I doubted whether the crontab command will not work for particular user.. I tried it from the "root" user....which is the root user....tried the command via SSH or Putty and the response was "command not found". Please find a solution for this, also please give me an idea whether my concept works fine...

Comment: You have root access on a shared host?

Answer (score 0):

> please suggest a way to find its location

Try

```
whereis crontab
```